# regExp problem - string is matched but it should not match

Tags: php, regex

iam trying to check if an user has permission to manage an group:

Expression (`ou=|||`) is the string I'm looking for

```
/^OU=|||$|,OU=|||$/i
```

On a string like `"ou=whatever"`, it returns true (-:

I am sure it's a problem with the pipes, but I have no idea how to solve this.

I am using PHP 5.x with `preg_match`.

Comment: See [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php).

Comment: Just for clarification, your original regex means `OU=` at start of line, or nothing (anywhere in a string, i.e. anything), or nothing, or end of line (which matches every expression), or ...

Comment: hum not sure what you mean with preg_quote it works it maches ou=whatever but not ou=|||

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the pipes and include some parenthesis for better readability:

```
/(^OU=\|\|\|$)|(,OU=\|\|\|$)/i
```

Comment: thanks! str_replace was the solution.. sometines you run against a wall in the monring!

Answer (score 3):

Pipes are metacharacters in a regular expression (meaning "or"). You need to escape them:

```
/^OU=\|{3}$|,OU=\|{3}$/i
```

Are you sure that you're using the start- and end-of-string anchors correctly? Right now, this regex will only match the strings

```
OU=|||
```

and

```
<any number of characters>,OU=|||
```

Comment: +1 for the diagnostic.  I would imagine the OP really needs `(^|,)OU=\|{3}(,|$)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$has_permission = in_array('OU=|||', explode(',', $permission_string));
```